# JList is not updated within a worker thread model

Tags: java, multithreading, jlist

Withing a worker thread, Java runs my methods and in one of the methods, a `JList` is filled. Problem is that, when I run the program, the JList is not getting updated however by debugging with Netbeans, the list gets updated properly!!

How that can be justified?

The code looks like

```
public class TheFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    public TheFrame() {
      theFile = new ExcelFile();
      initComponents();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private void initComponents() {
        model = new DefaultListModel();
        effectList = new javax.swing.JList<>();
        effectList.setModel(model);
        pack();
    }                       
    /* worker threads is here */
    private ExcelFile theFile;
    private DefaultListModel<String> model;
    private javax.swing.JList<String> effectList;
}
```

The implementation of worker is

```
    private void Load(JFileChooser fc, int i)
    {
        /* i is an identifier which shows which button has been pressed */
        /* stuffs for creating a please wait window */
        SwingWorker<Void, Void> worker = new SwingWorker<Void, Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground() throws InterruptedException {
                if ( i == 1 ) {
                  List< String > ls  = theFile.updateEffectList();
                  for (int i = 0; i < ls.size(); i++) {
                      // The following line works fine in the debug mode
                      // but By running the project, it will be empty
                      model.addElement(ls.get(i));
                  }
                  effectList.setVisible(true);
                }
                return null;
            }
            @Override
            protected void done() {
                loading.dispose(); // this is the please wait window
            }
        };
        worker.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
            //System.out.println(evt.getPropertyName());
            Object value = evt.getNewValue();
            if (value instanceof SwingWorker.StateValue) {
                SwingWorker.StateValue state = (SwingWorker.StateValue) value;
                switch (state) {
                    case DONE: {
                        try {
                            worker.get();
                        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException ex) {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Failed");
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        });
        worker.execute();
        loading.setVisible(true); // this is the please wait window
    }
```

There are some discussions about that but I didn't got my answer there.

Comment: 1. the posted code seems incomplete, missing important parts like adding the JList to the frame, including not so important parts like `pack()`  2. the model is being changed in doInBackground which does not run in EDT: "All Swing components and related classes, unless otherwise documented, must be accessed on the event dispatching thread. ...This restriction also applies to models attached to Swing components"

Comment: 3. IMO there is no need for the PropertyChangeListener, the call to `get()` with the handling of Exceptions can be done in `done()` - to solve point 2. (previous comment) override the `process()` method and call `publish()` inside the loop of `doInBackground`

Comment: I will post the complete code later. Meanwhile i think the important thing is item 2 as you said. Can you explain more on how to rewrite that. Where should i call publish() and other thing? What is a proper document for that?

Comment: I moved the `for` loop for `model.addElement(ls.get(i));` to `propertyChange()`. Is that all? Seems to be working!

Comment: kind of the opposite of what I proposed... see my answer - there should be no need for the listener - could have been done in the `done` method (déjà vu!!)

Answer (score 0):

Here a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (maybe not *that* minimal)!

I also urge you to study the [`SwingWorker`'s documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) and see the [Swing's Threading Policy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/package-summary.html#threading).

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Cursor;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;


public class TheFrame  {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TheFrame();
    } 


    private JFrame frame;

    private JList<String> list;
    private DefaultListModel<String> model;

    private JButton load;


    private TheFrame() {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(this::initGUI);
    }

    private void initGUI() {
        // runs on EDT
        model = new DefaultListModel<>();

        list = new JList<>(model);

        // for testing
        load = new JButton("Load");
        load.addActionListener(ev -> load());

        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.add(new JScrollPane(list), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(load, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(400, 300);
        frame.validate();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void load() {
        // runs on EDT
        frame.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.WAIT_CURSOR));
        SwingWorker<Void, String> worker = new SwingWorker<Void, String>() {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
                // runs on worker Thread
                List<String> ls = updateList();
                for (String string : ls) {
                    simulateDelay(200);
                    publish(string);
                }
                return null;
            }
            @Override
            protected void process(List<String> chunks) {
                // runs on EDT
                for (String string : chunks) {
                    model.addElement(string);
                }
            }
            @Override
            protected void done() {
                // runs on EDT
                try {
                    get();  // check for Exceptions
                } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    frame.setCursor(Cursor.getDefaultCursor());
                }
            }
        };
        worker.execute();
    }

    // generate some sample data
    private List<String> updateList() {
        simulateDelay(500);
        List<String> data = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g");
        Collections.shuffle(data);  // just fun.. erh, testing
        return data;
    }

    // for testing only, do not use this in production/real code
    private static void simulateDelay(long delay) {
        try { 
            Thread.sleep(delay); 
        } catch (@SuppressWarnings("unused") InterruptedException ignored) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason for putting a delay of 200ms?

Comment: **no!** simulateDelay should suggest that is only simulating the delay of a real system... well, the only reason was to just (try to) be a bit more like doing some real work like reading a file.

Comment: Since I have created a modal please wait window and it is a modal window, it has to be removed after the completion of the task, e.g. filling the JList. However, with this code, it won't disappeared. I also put `loading.dispose()` after the `get()` line. Please refer to my code where I wrote a comment in the worker section.

Comment: That is the reason why I used worker model. While my program is working, a please wait window is shown and it is modal. It has to be gone after the completion of JList

Comment: if it modal it is blocking the EDT - so the methods that run on the EDT will not run until the modal dialog is disposed. If you really need/want the modal dialog, it must be disposed inside doInBackground..This also means that there is no reason to use a SwingWorker, a simple Thread would suffice, since there is no way to *visually* update the JList while the EDT is blocked.

Comment: Can you explain the last sentence of your comment? which document is worth to read for that?

Comment: there are links in that sentence (answer), just click on them... "SingWorker's doument" and "Swing's Threading Policy" (they should appear blue)